svnsync: E160028: 'Directory' is out of date
On the SVN master server, a directory was removed, and svnsync synchronized/updated all revisions to the mirror server until it reached the commit where the directory was deleted, resulting in the error message: 'svnsync: E160028: 'Directory' is out of date.' any fix for this ? trying to sync manually gives the same error
I have tried svnsync manually and i can confirm there is no lock on the revision
